# Designing Automated Database Using SQL and Yahoo Finance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I want to create a simple database using SQL (MySQL workbench) that automatically updates open and close prices from yahoo finance for various stocks. I am beginner in database design, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: this is a broad question. can't be answered here

Comment: There are many many Q&A on this site that discuss the schema.  Or is your question about how to access Yahoo Finance?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize about the broad question but if anybody runs into this issue as I did and isn't sure where to start (like I was)....This is what you need to look into:

Build a data pipeline using your API. You do this through an ETL process. After learning about the ETL process, you will figure out that you can make this feed run daily, and download the data as necessary. Finally, you can use something like Airflow to monitor and schedule these projects.